# Grails: mapping column names of a field and a belongsTo of the same type

Tags: grails, types, mapping, belongs-to

I'm trying to map the column names of this class:

```java
class Amount{

    String total //Total amount of something
    String type  //Type of amount, Dollars, %, Times something
    Bonification bonificationRate  //the amount can be "x times another bonification"

    static belongsTo = [parentBonification: Bonification]

    static mapping = {
       table "AMOUNTS"
       total column: "AMOU_TTOTAL"
       type column: "AMOU_TTYPE"
       parentBonification column: "BONI_CID"
       bonificationRate column: "BONI_TRATE_CID"
    }

}


class Bonification {  
    //among other things:  
    Amount amount
}
```

The thing is none of the field with the `Bonification` class are created in the DB,
not with the name I give them and neither with the default suppossed names.

Comment Edit:

1. Both are Domain Classes;
2. Datasource is on `dbCreate = "update"`
3. I dropped the Table in Oracle and let Grails create it again. Still no Bonification columns.
4. I can not `dbCreate = "create-drop"` because there is data that I can't delete for now.
5. I mounted a new local Derby Database with `dbCreate = create-drop`. Still no luck.

**(PD: All other fields are persisted and mapped with the right column names, only those two `Bonification` fields are the problem)**
Is there another way of doing this?

> Grails: 1.3.9
>   BD: Oracle 9

**Edit for asked DataSource.groovy**
(External file accessed from Config.groovy
`grails.config.locations = [ "file:${extConfig}/${appName}Config.groovy"]`)

```
package xx.xxx.xxxx.xxxXxxx

dataSource 
{
    pooled = true
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"    
    username = "XXX"
    password = "XXX" 
    properties {
                maxActive = 100
                maxIdle = 25
                minIdle = 5
                initialSize = 5
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 60000
                maxWait = 10000
                validationQuery = "select 1 from dual"
                }

}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}

// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
println "Including external DataSource"
        dataSource {            
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxx.xxx.xx:xxxx:XXXX"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are both Bonification and Amount supposed to be domain classes or is one a value object?

Comment: Both are domain classes, I didn't want to put all the other properties of `Bonification` in here.

Comment: They aren't created in the database or they exists but with another name? Your dataSouce is setted to create columns and relations?

Comment: That columns doesn't exist at all in the table `AMOUNTS` or in any other table.
My datasource is with `dbCreate = "update"`

Comment: That dbCreate setting is pretty limited. Set it to create-drop or use database migrations.

Comment: Posting your DataSource.groovy would help people explore the cause.

Comment: +1 to DataSource posting

Comment: Ok. Thanks.
I edited the post and Added DataSource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, finally I got it.

I used the "mappedBy" property.

http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Domain%20Classes/mappedBy.html

The documentation ([6.2.1.2 One-to-many](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html)) said that is for use in the "hasMany" side. That confused me because I didn't have a hasMany but rather two field of the same type in `Class Amount`.
And what I really had to do was to use the mappedBy property, not in the Amount Class, but in the Bonification Class that has just one reference to `Amount`.

And with that I tell to the `Amount Class`, wich Bonification he has to back reference so "he" doesn't get confused, and take the `bonificationRate` field just as a field and not as a reference as I think he was doing before.

```
class Amount{

    String total //Total amount of something
    String type  //Type of amount, Dollars, %, Times something
    Bonification bonificationRate  //the amount can be "x times another bonification"

    static belongsTo = [parentBonification: Bonification]

    static mapping = {
       table "AMOUNTS"
       total column: "AMOU_TTOTAL"
       type column: "AMOU_TTYPE"
       parentBonification column: "BONI_CID"
       bonificationRate column: "BONI_TRATE_CID"
    }

}


class Bonification {  
    //among other things:  
    Amount amount

    static mappedBy = [amount: "parentBonification"]
}
```

That didn't created the `parentBonification "BONI_CID" column` but it Did created the `bonificationRate "BONI_TRATE_CID"` wich I needed.

Sorry if it's too messy. Thanks for the time and help anyway.