# How to override grails/hibernate relationship column name

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have a Persons domain class and a Signatory domain class that refers to Persons via the simple following declaration:

Persons person

Hibernate then creates a column entitled person_id in table Signatory. I need it to be something else. How to override this? I tried using mappedBy but its not working. The correct syntax is?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141506/grails-mapping-column-names-of-a-field-and-a-belongsto-of-the-same-type

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation : http://docs.grails.org/3.1.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html

```
static mapping = {
    person column: "customColumnName"
}
```